# how to understand while loop - linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So I am learning on my own, and ran across this code for reversing a linked list:

```
function reverseLinkedList(linkedList) {
  let node = linkedList.head;
  let first = node;
  let next = null;
  let prev = null;

  while (next = node.next) {
    node.next = prev;
    prev = node;
    node = next;
  }

  linkedList.head = node;
  linkedList.head.next = prev;  
  linkedList.tail = first;

  return linkedList;
}
```

Now my question is, how in the...How does while(next = node.next) work if it is not a conditional statement. My guess is that it turns into node.next becomes undefined when reaching the tail node and calling .next, and that in turn breaks the while loop. However, I am not positive this is the case.

Comment: node.next is live, when it hits null it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. As you pointed out, the `while` loop stops executing the moment `node.next` becomes `undefined`. It uses the right-hand side of `next = node.next` as conditional. In this case `node.next`.

To illustrate my point, consider the following piece of code:

```js
let i = 0
const values = [1, 2, undefined, 3]
while (x = values[i]) {
  console.log(x);
  i += 1;
}
```

This will print:

```
1
2
```

Stopping the execution the moment it reaches `undefined` (Any [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value would produce the same effect)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it is semantically equal to:

```js
next = node.next
while (next) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Meaning, when `next == null` (or any falsy value), the loop's condition is `false`, therefore the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (next = node.next) {
    node.next = prev;
    prev = node;
    node = next;
}
```

is same as

```
next = node.next
while (next != NULL) {
    node.next = prev;
    prev = node;
    node = next;
    next = node.next
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (and many other languages with this sort of syntax) the result of an assignment statement is the value assigned.  So, in this case, the while evaluates each node which is either a value or not.  This is so you can chain assignments like `x = y = 5`, but also you can evaluate them as conditionals too.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment